# Where is the difference when creating the same app for iPhone and then iPhone4?

Tags: iphone

Is anybody able to explain how do you create the same app for the two versions of the iPhone? I have been reading the Developer Guide and a couple of books but I can't figure where should I start at. The only difference i found is in the screenshots' sizes but really, what should I do different when buidling my app: 
- is there a different process or feature in the SDK or Interface Builder? should i start building it for iPhone3, or iPhone4? Is it the same thing? How would I be able to make it available for both versions at once?
Any feedback would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although you can optimize graphics for an iPhone 4, you really don't have to do anything (except maybe provide 2 or 3 icons).  An app for an iPhone 3 will run on an iPhone 4 with no updates or changes or new default images.  I have tons of old apps on my new iPhone.